# Vimeo PHP API How do I add my recently Uploaded Video to a Channel?

Tags: php, api, vimeo, channel

I finally got my batch Uploader to work and it is fast and efficient.  I am also able to update the Name & Description metadata within the uploader script.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation where it even shows how to set the name & description text (I got that code from stackoverflow and it works).  How can I get list of all possible supported parameter values and syntax for $lib->request and can this method be used to add a video by id to a channel name?
 Here is what I've tried but still can't assign video to channel.

```
<?PHP
$lib->request($uri, array('name' => 'This is the Title text for my video'), 'PATCH'); // This works perfectly
$lib->request($uri, array('description' => 'This is the description for my video'), 'PATCH'); // This works perfectly
$lib->request($uri, array('channels' => 'This is the name of a channel'), 'POST'); // This does not work but no errors
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing a video is a `PATCH` request to `/videos/{video_id}` (aka the video's URI). You can read more about that endpoint here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D. You don't need to make a new request for every parameter, so request 1 and 2 can be merged together.

To add a video to a channel, check out this endpoint: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/channels#PUT%2Fchannels%2F%7Bchannel_id%7D%2Fvideos%2F%7Bvideo_id%7D. The basic idea is you merge the channel URI (`/channels/{channel_id}`) with the video uri (`/videos/{video_id}`) and make a `PUT` request to that url.

For example:

`PUT /channels/12445/videos/612342`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer is so simple that is embarrassing!

The code was working the whole time but the reason that I didn't know it was working is because the video was still processing async when the attempt to add it to the channel was executed.

To solve the problem I wrote a second application that will add a batch of videos to a given channel. This application will be run after all processing is completed by the first application by querying mysql database.

I want to thank everyone that put some thought into this for me and apologize for any time that you may have devoted.